# Python 3 Unitesting: "ModuleNotFoundError" when executing in console in unix

Tags: python-3.x

if I have written a unittest, that passes, if I run my tests.py in IDE Pycharm. If I use the console (in unix) however and start the unittest with:

> python3 tests/tests.py

I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpermodule'

My folder structure looks like this:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpBwc.png)

The files look like the following:

Mytest.py:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
```

tests.py:

```
from helpermodule import Mytest
import unittest
```

What am I missing here? I have read several posts concerning the problem, but I could not find a solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem, the simple solution is to call the test.py with right parameters:

`python3 -m unittest tests/tests.py`

see also:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface